# Can I redirect macOS lpr output to a PDF instead of to a printer?

Tags: macos, file, printing

I am looking for a method of sending the output of macOS `lpr` to a PDF file instead of to a printer.

When I use the `lpr` command in macOS to print a text file to a printer, it uses the Menlo font for the text, so, clearly, it is not simply sending raw text but applying formatting. I am trying to figure out how to redirect that formatted output to a PDF file instead of to a printer.

I've tried piping the output to pstopdf, but even if that's a possible solution, I can't make it work.

I need to make this a portable solution, so that I can distribute it as part of an app, and therefore I can't require someone else to install brew or any other software on their system. This means I can't use something like `enscript` which isn't native to macOS to convert a text file to PostScript, then convert that to PDF and print it. I've tried using `nenscript` but it does strange things to formatting and doesn't produce the correct output the way the `lpr` command does.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the `lpr` output into a file?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

`cupsfilter -i text/plain inputfile > outputfile.pdf`